# Manipulate Data of auto_increment with insert ignore

Tags: mysql, database

i am creating an id table for a column named symbols. this is the code i am using

```
begin
insert ignore into symbolid(symbol) select distinct symbol from ord;
end
```

now table symbolid has a column named id which is auto_incremented. now table ord is updated with time so i need to keep updating symbolid as well for which i will be calling the above procedure. now the problem is that there are gaps being created because though symbols are not inserted it seems auto_increment value is changed. i found solutions for single value insertion for this problem but nothing where a huge set of data is being inserted. i prefer to not use cursors and loops as they are slow but all solutions are welcome

Comment: It shouldn't matter that gaps are being created. You shouldn't rely on the ids to be consecutive.

Comment: but as the procedure will be called multiple times , gaps will keep on increasing and that's unnecessary imo ,as if someone requires a loop to be called on symbolid , he might have many iterations futile as many numbers wont have an id to correspond to

Comment: You should never have code trying to guess what the valid primary keys are in the database. If you want to iterate over the ids, you should execute a query to select the ids and iterate over the results.

Comment: it maybe a bad practice , but is it wrong to ask such a question , because this downvote does baffle me

Comment: I think this is a fine question. I didn't downvote you. StackOverflow downvotes baffle me too sometimes.